# Evaluation of a Christoffel Symbol

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, smooth-manifolds

I am a bit confused on the notation for a certain evaluation of a Christoffel symbol. In particular, I am confused about the following formula:

$$\Gamma_{ij}^k = \frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(\partial_i g_{jl} - \partial_l g_{li} + \partial_j g_{li}),$$

where $g$ is my semi-Riemannian metric.

I am particularly confused about the variety of the indices, what $g_{ab}$ is, and why the vector field $\partial_c$ is being applied to whatever $g_{ab}$ is.

---

I *had* thought, if $\{x^i,x^j\}$ where the coordinates, that:
$$g_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix}
g(x^i,x^i) & g(x^i,x^j)\\
g(x^j,x^i) & g(x^j,x^j)
\end{bmatrix},$$
but then I would not understand how the vector fields applied to them would work. Using this same idea for $g_{ij}$, I thought $g^{kl}$ from the equation would have represented the inverse of this matrix.

A concern of mine also was that I do not understand the extra indices $k,l$, unless they are being summed over in some way, in the style of Einstein summation notation.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g_{\mu \nu }$ is called the metric tensor. It is related to the Riemannian metric by $g = {g_{\mu \nu }} \cdot d{x^\mu } \otimes d{x^\nu }$, where the Einstein summation convention is in effect and the $d{x^\mu }$ form the dual basis of the cotangent space.

The Christoffel symbols, $\Gamma _{\mu \nu }^\alpha  = \frac{1}{2}{g^{\alpha \beta }}\left( {{\partial _\mu }{g_{\nu \beta }} + {\partial _\nu }{g_{\mu \beta }} - {\partial _\beta }{g_{\mu \nu }}} \right)$, are written assuming the Einstein summation convention.

**In example**: Take the metric tensor of the Schwarzschild geometry

$${g_{\mu \nu }} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {1 - \frac{{{r_s}}}{r}}&0&0&0 \\ 
  0&{\frac{1}{{1 - \frac{{{r_s}}}{r}}}}&0&0 \\ 
  0&0&{{r^2}}&0 \\ 
  0&0&0&{{r^2}{{\sin }^2}\theta } 
\end{array}} \right)$$

The Christoffel symbols of this metric would form 4 4x4 matrices: $\Gamma _{\mu \nu }^0$,$\Gamma _{\mu \nu }^1$,$\Gamma _{\mu \nu }^2$, and $\Gamma _{\mu \nu }^3$.

In our basis the vectors ${\partial _\mu }$ are equal to $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{\partial _0}} \\ 
  {{\partial _1}} \\ 
  {{\partial _2}} \\ 
  {{\partial _3}} 
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\partial /\partial t} \\ 
  {\partial /\partial r} \\ 
  {\partial /\partial \theta } \\ 
  {\partial /\partial \varphi } 
\end{array}} \right)\ $.

So for instance if we look at the component $\Gamma _{01}^0$ we could see it simplifies to $\frac{1}{2}{g^{00}}{\partial _1}{g_{00}} = \frac{1}{2}{g^{00}}\frac{\partial }{{\partial r}}{g_{00}}$.

Plugging in the ${g_{00}}$ component of our metric tensor we can find that $\Gamma _{01}^0 = \frac{{{r_s}}}{{2{r^2}\left(1- {\frac{{{r_s}}}{r}} \right)}}$.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it has made a lot much clearer! I have a question though concerning $g^{\mu\nu}$ and how it is defined if $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the metric tensor. Additionally, I was wondering if the proper form for $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^0$ (for example) is to sum the entries of your $4\times 4$ matrix.

Comment: No, $\Gamma _{\mu \nu }^0 = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\Gamma _{00}^0}&{\Gamma _{01}^0}&{\Gamma _{02}^0}&{\Gamma _{03}^0} \\ 
  {\Gamma _{10}^0}&{\Gamma _{11}^0}&{\Gamma _{12}^0}&{\Gamma _{13}^0} \\ 
  {\Gamma _{20}^0}&{...}&{...}&{...} \\ 
  {\Gamma _{30}^0}&{...}&{...}&{...} 
\end{array}} \right)$.

Comment: Generally a summation is only implied if one index is contravariant and the other is covariant. i.e. ${v^\alpha }{v_\alpha } = \sum\limits_\alpha  {{v^\alpha }{v_\alpha }} $

Comment: ${g^{\mu \nu }}$ is the inverse of ${g_{\mu \nu }}$. You can see this through the relation ${g^{\alpha \beta }}{g_{\beta \gamma }} = \delta _\gamma ^\alpha $.

Comment: Why on Earth we never see those explicit calculations in Riemannian Geometry classes!?!?